# Borrar una clase al dar click

Tags: javascript

A ciertos elementos que se accede a ellos por su id y se les identifica como List les e querido borrar la clase si, y solo si, tiene la clase `ViewDelett0element`. El código de abajo fue intento de ello, me gustaria saber si hay alguna propiedad u otra forma de poder hacerlo.

La clase es ViewDelett0element y primero la pongo con este código:

```
for (var p = 0; p <= List.children.length -1; p++) {
    List.children[p].addEventListener("click" , function() {
        this.setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element");
    });
}
```

Y luego la quito con este otro

```
for (var k = 0; k <= List.children.length -1; k++){
    List.children[k].addEventListener("click" , function(){
        if(child.ClassName === ViewDelett0element){this.setAttribute("class", "");}
    });
}
```

Lo que pasa es que al dar un primer click se agrega una clase al elemento y en el segundo click se le deselecciona o quita la clase , supongo que al querer quitar la clase con el segundo click tambien actua la otra funcion que agrega la clase y parace como si no hubiese cambio.

Comment: La clase es ViewDelett0element y quiero borrarla al dar click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora mismo estás comprobando que la clase coincida exactamente con el valor de la variable `ViewDelett0element`, si lo que quieres es que compare con la cadena `"ViewDelett0element"` deberías entrecomillar el valor. Además el atributo que te dará la clase no es `ClassName` sino `className` (con la c en minúscula). Por último, otro cambio es que no defines `child` en ningún sitio, deberías usar `this` para referirte al elemento hijo.

Cambiando eso el código quedaría así:

```
for (var k = 0; k <= List.children.length -1; k++){
    List.children[k].addEventListener("click" , function(){
        if(this.className === "ViewDelett0element"){this.setAttribute("class", "");}
    });
}
```

---

Edición: para solucionar el problema de que no funciona porque una función cancela a la otra, lo que podrías hacer es ponerlo todo en una única función:

- Si el elemento no tiene la clase (caso inicial) y se pulsa en él, se añade la clase
- Si el elemento contiene la clase, se borra.

En una única función sería así:

```
for (var k = 0; k <= List.children.length -1; k++){
  List.children[k].addEventListener("click" , function(){
    if(this.className === "ViewDelett0element"){
      this.setAttribute("class", "");
    } else 
    {
      this.setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element");
    }
  });
}
```

Puedes ver una demo aquí:

```js
List = document.getElementById("aux");
for (var k = 0; k <= List.children.length -1; k++){
  List.children[k].addEventListener("click" , function(){
    if(this.className === "ViewDelett0element"){
      this.setAttribute("class", "");
    } else 
    {
      this.setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="aux">
<div class="">A</div>
<div class="">B</div>
<div class="">C</div>
<div class="">D</div>
<div class="">E</div>
<div class="">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: oooo eso no lo recorde , muchas gracias lo intentare en mi codigo

Comment: Bueno aun no me funciono

Comment: @EmmanuelRuiz Corregí un fallo. Mira el código ahora, y lo puedes ver funcionando correctamente aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/dxeo0z7n/

Comment: Lo que pasa es que al dar un primer click se aggrega una clase al elemento y en el segundo click se le deselecciona o quita la clase , supongo que al querer quitar la clase con el segundo click tambien actua la otra funcion que agrega la clase  y parace como si no ubiese cambio , las 2 funciones para agre gar y quitar son:

Comment: Quitar:    for (var k = 0; k <= List.children.length -1; k++){
List.children[k].addEventListener("click" , function(){
if(this.ClassName === "ViewDelett0element"){this.setAttribute("class", "");}});}

Comment: poner: for (var p = 0; p <= List.children.length -1; p++) {
List.children[p].addEventListener("click" , function(){this.setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element");});}

Comment: @EmmanuelRuiz comprueba la última actualización

Comment: Muchisimas gracias  Alvaro Montoro , a funcionado Muy bien el codigo , al parecer no se quitaba la clase que tenia que borrar tambien porque al dar un primer click otra funcion agregaba una clase y como al ver que esta la borra la clase actua en un elemento child sin clase agregandola de nuevo , era por eso que creia que no funcionaba .

Comment: Alvaro Montoro , muchas gracias , diculpa no haber respondido antes , ya me funciono mi codigo gracias a ti.